# BackboneJS - in destroy method: how to cancel firing events in done callback?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Question about a bit more advanced version of BackboneJS Todo List

[BackboneJS Todo List http://todomvc.com/examples/backbone/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE9AU.png)

On click "X" link I have simple handler (events['click .destroy'] = 'clear',):

```
clear: function () {
        this.model.destroy()
    },
```

As I can see, I can do something like this:

```
clear: function () {
        this.model.destroy()
            .fail(function(err) {})
            .done(function(resData) {
              // HERE I would like to cancel firing other events, like "destroy".


        })
    },
```

In done callback I can get info if there was some problem while deleting row from table. In current case - it is Doctrine2 exception related to Foreign Key Constraint. I catch it in my todos.php, set {success: false}, and wish in done callback use it to prevent HTML element "li" to be deleted from Todo list, as it happens now.

Is that so, when method model.destroy is called, no matter failed it or succeded, event "destroy" is fired, and because of that - element "li" is been removed from Todo List ?

Maybe I should use "request" event for collection?

What technique is best practice?

Could you please paste here some example (or link to example)?